# Let $X_{1}, ... , X_{n}$ independent Bernoulli variables with same parameter $p$. Prove that $X_{1} + ... + X_{n} \sim B(n,p)$.

Tags: probability

Let $X_{1}, ... , X_{n}$ independent Bernoulli variables with same parameter $p$. Prove that $X_{1} + ... + X_{n} \sim B(n,p)$.

I tried to prove it by induction, but I got stuck on the very first step. How should I show that I can observe each $X_{i}$ as $B(1,p)$? I mean, I know that sum $X_{1} + ... + X_{n}$ is interpreted as random variable $X$ and all those $X_{i}$ are i-th time of repeating the experiment but is the reversed claim valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition:

- A Bernoulli random variable $A$ with parameter $p$ has $\mathbb P(A=0)=1-p$ and $\mathbb P(A=1)=p$
- A binomial random variable $B$ with parameters $n$ and $p$ has $\mathbb P(B=k)={n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$ when $k \in \{0,1,\ldots, n\}$

When $n=1$, these definitions say the same thing